# Capture the print statement "Messages" in SSRS report in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a sql server sp (it runs on SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008, 2012) that returns html code using print statement as "Messages" not as "Results"

The html code is used to build html web page and I cannot use the select statement due to the length of characters returned.

I need to capture the print statement "Messages" in SSRS report to build the web page. If it is not possible, is there a way to capture it in SQL server and insert the "Messages" in a temp table?

Comment: Please post your sp...

Comment: change the `PRINT` statement to SELECT and use an OUTPUT variable of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to hold the html returned by the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
     (at the end of the proc)

```
create table #msgs (line1 varchar(2000))
insert into #msgs 
select 'This is a very long msg'+col1 from table25

select line1 from #msgs
```

Comment: What is table25? How do you insert the print statement messages in the temp table?

Comment: I thought that you had a table of data that you want to insert into your print lines and you were getting your data from a table I arbitrarily named table25.